# Change Android's spinner dialog background on 'dropdown' mode

Tags: android, android-spinner

HOw can I change it? The `android:popupBackground` property's doc says:

> Background drawable to use for the dropdown in 
>    spinnerMode="dropdown". [reference, color]

But setting this property has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Have you declared in the xml that android:spinnerMode = "dropdown" ? 
If not, do it. Then try again to change android:popupBackground. :)

*Links*

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:popupBackground

Comment: man i was scratching my head why popupBackground was not working! i changed spinnermode to drop down n it works thanks alot!